# To pass input field value of type string in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular6

I have component called `customer` which is used to add new customers. The **component** code as  follows:

> HTML

```
<div >
  <form [formGroup]="addForm">

        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstname" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.firstname.hasError('required')">
              Please enter first name
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastname" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.lastname.hasError('required')">
              Please enter last name
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>


        <div>
          <mat-radio-group formControlName="gender">
            <div>Gender</div>
            <mat-radio-button  value="Male">Male</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="Female">Female</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </div>

        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Email Address"  formControlName="email" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.email.hasError('required') ">
              Please enter email address
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>


    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="onAdd()">ADD</button>
    </div>

  </form>
```

> TS

```
  import { Component, OnInit, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import {
    FormBuilder,
    FormControl,
    FormGroup,
    Validators,
  } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
 import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

 @Component({
   selector: 'asd-customer',
   templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css'],
 })

export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
 public addForm: FormGroup;
 public someContact: IContact;

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
      public customersService: CustomersService) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
 this.addForm = this.fb.group({
   firstname: [null, [Validators.required],
   lastname: [null, [Validators.required],
   email: ['', [Validators.required],
   gender: [null],

  });
 }

 public onAdd(): void {
   this.someContact = this.addForm.value;
   this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someContact);
 }


}
```

> model.ts file

```
export interface IContact {
  firstName:      string;
  lastName:       string;
  gender:         string;
  eMailAddresses: string[];
}
```

The expected **JSON** after the POST request:

```
 {
   "firstName": "Alfien",
   "lastName": "Urlich",
   "gender": "Male",
   "eMailAddresses": ["aurlich6v@hotmail.com"],
  }
```

When i fill every input fields of the **form** and tried performing **http POST** operation. I am getting warning as **Bad Request** because of `email`.
Below is the warning:

[image]

When i perform **POST** operation without filling `email(input field)` the POST happens fine, the **JSON** appears like this:

```
  {

   "firstName": "Lee",
   "lastName": "Cooper",
   "gender": "Male",
}
```

What's wrong with the code ??

Comment: you are using `json.parse` somewhere in code?

Comment: No i am not using.

Comment: sorry , my bad `JSON.stirngify`?

Comment: I am not using both methods.

Comment: @PrashanthGH check your back what they want or which type of  `eMailAddresses` this field string or string array?

Comment: The email won't just magically become an array because you specify it as an array in the interface. Your form model type is a string, which is also what will be sent to the server, unless your service is what converts it into an array. Maybe post that code so we can actually know what is happening.

Comment: You need `service` code??

Comment: In your screenshot, there is an `error` node that is collapsed. Expand it fully and see what is in there.

Comment: Okay i will post it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in Email-address field In Form-control it is an single string and in interface it is an array.So if u want to add it set it like below,

```
public someContact: IContact={};
    public onAdd(): void {
     this.someContact.firstName = this.addForm.value.firstName;
     this.someContact.lastname = this.addForm.value.lastname;
     this.someContact.gender = this.addForm.value.gender; 
     this.someContact.eMailAddresses=[]
     this.someContact.eMailAddresses.push(this.addForm.value.email);
    }
```

change interface as follows

```
export interface IContact {
  firstName ?:      string;
  lastName ?:       string;
  gender ?:         string;
  eMailAddresses ?: string[];
}
```

but according to your scenario there will be only one email address in everytime you submit.

Comment: Getting this warning : **ERROR TypeError: this.someContact.eMailAddresses.push is not a function**

Comment: please initialize someContact as public someContact: IContact={} and before pushing intialize array as this.someContact.eMailAddresses=[ ]

Comment: Now the `email` as stored in DB as `null`

Comment: I tried setting `public someContact: IContact = {};` Getting this warning **Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IContact'.**

Comment: is the expected JSON is correct? can u show me the JSON after submitting

Comment: JSON ===> **{
        "eMailAddresses": [
            null
        ],
        "firstName": "Lee",
        "lastName": "Cooper",
        "birthDate": "2018-12-02T18:30:00Z",
        "gender": "Male",

    }**

Comment: can u give me a console.log of this.addForm.value.email?

Comment: It's logging as `undefined`.

Comment: that means its not getting a value also set it to null when initializing form group and if u can enter a valid email address and give me console.log of this.addForm.value